# How to trunc columns with spark-redshift if the column content is too long?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I am wondering about how to truncate columns with `spark-redshift` if the columns content is too long, rather than return an error.

Comment: What command(s) were you running? Were you extracting from Redshift, or inserting data into Redshift? Amazon Redshift has a [`TRUNCATECOLUMNS`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-truncatecolumns) option when loading data via the `COPY` command. Not sure if it is usable in `spark-redshift`.

Comment: Yeah familiar with that, I'm wondering if there is a flag in the spark redshift library to invoke that

Comment: Sorry I won't have a chance to verify the solution till I get into work tomorrow.  Then I'll accept and close!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `spark-redshift` connector uses the `redshift-jdbc` connector under the hood. This connector is used to automatically trigger the appropriate `COPY` and `UNLOAD` commands on *AWS Redshift*.

But you can specify `extracopyoptions` which is a list of extra options to append to the *AWS Redshift* `COPY` command when loading data, e.g. `TRUNCATECOLUMNS` in your case.

**Note** that since these options are appended to the end of the `COPY` command, only options that make sense at the end of the command can be used, but that should cover most possible use cases.